# What's this new column in -XX:+PrintCompilation output?

Tags: java, optimization, java-8, jvm-hotspot

While using `-XX:+PrintCompilation` recently (JDK 8r111) to examine method compilation, I noticed a new column which doesn't appear in the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086690/understanding-the-output-of-xxprintcompilation) I can [find](https://gist.github.com/chrisvest/2932907) on the topic:

```
          this column
               |
               |
               v
600    1  s    3       java.util.Hashtable::get (69 bytes)
601    4       3       java.lang.Character::toLowerCase (6 bytes)
601    8       3       java.io.UnixFileSystem::normalize (75 bytes)
602   12       3       java.lang.ThreadLocal::get (38 bytes)
602   14       3       java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap::getEntry (42 bytes)
602   18       2       java.lang.String::startsWith (72 bytes)
602   10       4       java.lang.String::equals (81 bytes)
602    2 %     4       java.lang.String::hashCode @ 24 (55 bytes)
602   16  s!   3       sun.misc.URLClassPath::getLoader (197 bytes)
603   23     n 0       java.lang.System::arraycopy (native)   (static)
604   27     n 0       sun.misc.Unsafe::getObjectVolatile (native)
```

Any clue what it means? It seems to vary between 0 and 3, with native methods always 0, and other methods always non-zero.

Comment: http://alexandrastech.blogspot.com/2016/06/jit-fun-part-3-xxprintcompilation.html

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - answered my question, so it's good enough for an answer.

Comment: I'm no expert on the compiler levels. I'll let someone with more experience give a more detailed answer.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - fair enough. If no one does I'll write it myself. To be fair, you don't necessarily need to be an expert  to write an answer, but I appreciate your comment nonetheless.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a *tier* in Tiered Compilation mode.

- At tiers 1, 2, 3 the code is compiled by C1 with different amount of extra profiling. It may sound counterintuitive, but the most optimized of them is tier 1 since it has no profiling overhead (and no chance to be further optimized).
- At tier 4 the code is compiled by C2. To produce highly optimized code C2 requires execution statistics gathered at tier 3 or during interpretation.

Here is how Tiered Compilation flow looks like. You may find the explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601841/how-does-the-jvm-decided-to-jit-compile-a-method-categorize-a-method-as-hot/35614237#35614237).

[image: HotSpot Tiered Compilation]

More details can be found in the [HotSpot source code comments](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/2b2511bd3cc8/src/share/vm/runtime/advancedThresholdPolicy.hpp#l34), which defines the levels as follows:

- level 0 - interpreter
- level 1 - C1 with full optimization (no profiling)
- level 2 - C1 with invocation and backedge counters
- level 3 - C1 with full profiling (level 2 + MDO)
- level 4 - C2